# VS201 - Referencing forms in solutions sub-folders

Tags: visual-studio-2010

My solution's files are becoming difficult to easily locate so I though I would create subfolders for some functions. Here is a screen capture of part of my Solution folder as shown in VS2010:

[image: VS2010 Solution Folders]

Here's a valid reference to SetupNetwork.NetworkSetup :

```
      showModule(typeof(NetworkSetup));
```

Here's a reference to SetupNetworkWizard in the same sub-directory:

```
  using (SetupNetwork.SetupNetworkWizard nw = new SetupNetwork.SetupNetworkWizard())
  {
    nw.ShowDialog();
  }
```

I appreciate there could be two forms with the same name located in different directories however I would have thought VS2010 would have **not** needed a reference to the sub-directory unless a conflict was found. Whilst one example above is a control and the other is a form, the two calls requirements are contradictory at least.

Is the above 'standard' or am I missing something in my setup of VS2010?

Comment: Abyss.xsd and AlertMaintenance.cs are interesting artifacts to this question.  The folders in your solution have nothing to do with the namespaces in your code.  The compiler cares about finding files first, namespace names next.  Finding files is taken care of.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to Hans Passant who pointed me in the right direction.

I didn't realise that forms created within a subfolder had that folders name appended to the projects namespace.